# cocoa wait for finish executions

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa

'm Having a problem running more then one method which contain NSTask to run  a script in the app bundle (using GDC to update the UI).

The problem is how to use one after the other, i.e. only when the previous one has been finished. 
Each of the methods as I said use NSTask to run the sh scripts, which have a duration of several seconds, and maybe even more than a minute (depending on which calculations are done).

Some things I tried unfortunately blocked the UI and this is not correct, because even the "Stop" button is locked.
I'm calling the methods as below:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runScript1:) withObject:blabla waitUntilDone:YES];
//some if statements here
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runScript2:) withObject:blabla waitUntilDone:YES]; how to wait for runScript1 completition??
//more script to call after
```

EDIT (adding example of runScript1)

```
    - (void)runScrip1:(NSArray*)args
{
    if (_operationPermitted == 1) {
        NSString *acq, *path;

        acq = [args objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [args objectAtIndex:1];

        dispatch_queue_t runQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        dispatch_async(runQueue, ^{

            @try {
                runScrip1Task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

                Scrip1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Scrip1.sh"];
                [_runScrip1sTask setLaunchPath:Scrip1];
                [_runScrip1Task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"skip", @"main", acq, path, nil]];

                [_runScrip1Task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/private/tmp"];
                [tasks addObject:_runScrip1Task];

                self.outputPipe               = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
                _runScrip1Task.standardOutput = self.outputPipe;
                _runScrip1Task.standardError  = self.outputPipe;

                [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){


                    self.display2.string = @"\nAcquiring all the data...";
                    NSData *output = [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] availableData];
                    NSString *outPutString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    // ----------------------------------------------- //

                    // here some code to update my UI

                    // ----------------------------------------------- //

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // manage text sobstitutions
                        [_outputView appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:outPutString attributes:_whiteTextwithArialFont]];
                        [_displayCenter scrollToEndOfDocument:self];
                    });

                    [[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
                }];

                [_runScrip1TaskTask launch];
                [_runScrip1TaskTask waitUntilExit];

            }
            // handle errors w/o app crashes
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Problem Running Task: %@", [exception description]);
                [self stopAllRunningsTasks];
            }
            @finally {
                _operationPermitted = YES;
                _finished = true;

            }
            if (_runScrip1TaskTask.terminationStatus > 0) {
                [self stopAllRunningsTasks];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone direct me to the right way, without blocking the user interface? 
thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the language you are using, please.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I added objective-c, and sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to leave your scripts asynchronous as they actually are inherently, and use "continuation".

Here is a sample code which should provide some help:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(int result);

- (void) runScript1WithParams:(NSArray*)params completion:(completion_t)completion {
   // Create and setup the task:
   NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
   ...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:[self.outputPipe fileHandleForReading] queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
       ...
   }];

   // set termination handler:
   task.terminationHandler = ^(NSTask* task){
        if (completion) {
            completion(task.terminationStatus);
        }
   };

   // handle errors if required
   ...

   // start the task asynchronously:
   [task launch];
}
```

Your other `runScript` method is implemented the same way.

Usage:

```
[self runScript1WithParams:params completion:^(int result){
    if (result == 0) {
        [self runScript2WithParams:params completion:^(int result){
            if (result == ...) {
                ...
            }
            else {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: amazing, I've just tried entering your code with just two tasks (to test), and this seems to work! 
I need to implement all the code and see what comes out, but in the meantime thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self runScript1:blabla];
    [self runScript2:blabla];
});
```

Alternately, you could create your own serial dispatch queue or NSOperationQueue with a max concurrent operation count of 1 and use that.

Comment: First of all thank you for responding.
I edited the first post, adding an example of runScript1 method.
I have to work with many of these blocks of code , which are very similar to each other , and some even use the command line instead of scripts.

To try your suggestion I need to make some changes , but in the meantime you have a better idea of ​​what I want to do .thanks

Comment: Oops forget.., "_operationPermitted" and "_finished = true;" are a bool that I'm tryng to force-wait for completition: "while !_fished...etc"